# Find which ios device being used

Tags: iphone, version, device, ios5.1

In my application i need to find which ios device is being used. Now i'm working in ios sdk 5.1

```
struct utsname systemInfo;
uname(&systemInfo);
NSString *platform=[NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

above code is perfectly working in ios SDK 5.0 but, not working in ios 5.1.
How can i find the device version in ios 5.1 like, iphone 3/3G/4/4s or ipad/ipad2 etc..

Comment: As the question is already answered. But for future, for all the device statistics you can use the posted code. Try & check it once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *device = [[UIDevice currentDevice]model ] ;
NSLog(@"%@",device);
```

it gives you device name (iPhone, iPad)

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
NSLog(@"%f",version);
```

it gives you ios version . not device name.

Comment: @Chinthu if the device is iphone 4s na.what is the version it shows

Answer (score 1):

The [`UIDevice`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) class can tell you plenty about the current device and its OS, and can probably be better trusted to return useful information on future devices / iOS versions than POSIX APIs like `uname` and `sysctl`.

However, you **should not** use a device name to determine whether to activate features in your app. This will cause your app to fail on newer devices, and your customers will be unhappy. For example, a while ago, some apps were testing for devices named "iPhone 4" in order to enable Retina display graphics... these apps didn't adapt well when the 4th-generation iPod touch and iPhone 4S came along with similar displays.

Instead, **test for the capabilities you need**. `UIDevice` knows about the screen size and form factor (aka "user interface idiom", iPhone/iPod vs iPad). Location Services can tell you what kind of position accuracy the device can provide. AVFoundation can tell you whether you have a still-only or video camera and what resolutions it can provide. In general, you can look to the APIs you're using for a feature to determine whether the device can support it.

Comment: Old answer but he has definitely a point. No one can guarantee that the posix apis will be accessible in future and guessing on unknown futuredevice can go easily wrong. Better stick with UIDevice.

Answer (score 0):

```
// To decide whether device is iPhone-4 or 3
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>


@interface UIDevice(Hardware)

- (NSString *) platform;

- (BOOL)hasRetinaDisplay;

- (BOOL)hasCamera;



@end

@implementation UIDevice(Hardware)

- (NSString *) platform{
        int mib[2];
        size_t len;
        char *machine;

        mib[0] = CTL_HW;
        mib[1] = HW_MACHINE;
        sysctl(mib, 2, NULL, &len, NULL, 0);
        machine = malloc(len);
        sysctl(mib, 2, machine, &len, NULL, 0);

        NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        free(machine);
        return platform;
}



- (BOOL)hasRetinaDisplay {
          NSString *platform = [self platform];
          BOOL ret = YES;
          if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"]) {
               ret = NO;
          }
          else
               if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    ret = NO;
          else 
               if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    ret = NO;
          else 
               if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      ret = NO;
          else
               if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      ret = NO;
          else
               if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      ret = NO;
       return ret;
}

- (BOOL)hasMultitasking {
       if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]) {
            return [self isMultitaskingSupported];
      }
      return NO;


}

- (BOOL)hasCamera {
       BOOL ret = NO;
      // check camera availability
      return ret;
}

@end
```